# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' in <file path> while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs

whenever I reload my website I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' in /Users/<name>/Desktop/Web_Development/ejs-challenge/views/home.ejs while compiling ejs
```

this is my app.js:

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const homeStartingContent = "<placeholder text>";
const contactContent = "<placeholder text>";
const aboutContent = "<placeholder text>";

const app = express();

let posts = [];

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home.ejs", {homeContent: homeStartingContent, 
  posts: posts});
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about.ejs", {aboutContent: aboutContent,});
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res){
  res.render("contact.ejs", {contactContent: contactContent,});
});

app.get("/compose", function(req, res){
  res.render("compose.ejs");
});

app.post("/compose", function(req, res){

  const post = {
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    body: req.body.postBody,
  };

  posts.push(post);

  res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  consol
```

e.log("Server started on port 3000");
});

this is my ejs:

```
<%- include('partials/header') -%>
<h1>Home</h1>
<p><%= homeContent %> </p>

<% posts.forEach(post => %>
    <h1> <%= post.title %> </h1>
    <p>  <%= post.body %> </p>
<% )) %>

<%- include('partials/footer') -%>
```

ejslint tells me this:

```
Unexpected token (6:9) in home.ejs
<h1><%= post.title %></h1>
    ^
```

I don't know how to fix it, I have already removed all of the ";" that was in my home.ejs file, I have tried to use a normal function as well,
Ejslint is not very helpful at least for me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two enclosing brackets  remove one

```
<% posts.forEach(post => %>
    <h1> <%= post.title %> </h1>
    <p>  <%= post.body %> </p>
<% )) %>
```

**change to this**

```
<% posts.forEach(post => %>
        <h1> <%= post.title %> </h1>
        <p>  <%= post.body %> </p>
    <% ) %>
```

Comment: i changed to `<% posts.forEach(post => %>
        <h1> <%= post.title %> </h1>
        <p>  <%= post.body %> </p>
<% ) %>` still getting the same error though, even restarted my server.

Comment: you forgot adding curly brackets after the arrow   ```<% posts.forEach(post =>{ %>
        <h1> <%= post.title %> </h1>
        <p>  <%= post.body %> </p>
    <%} ) %>```